# Send UILabel behind another UILabel (Swift)

Tags: swift, position, uilabel

I have a two overlapping UILabels onscreen and I wish to send the background UILabel in front of the front UILabel. How do I Do this? 
Is there a method of tagging them so that they will only move infant of each other as there are other UILabels and components on the screen also.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more comprehensive approach to this that gets exactly what you want is to extract the `views` array of your View and re-arrange it so that the view you care about is just 1 level higher:

```
let superview = UIView() //your view (probably self.view)
let labelToMove = UIView().removeFromSuperview() //label to move, do this so it can be re-inserted
let labelToStay = //your label

superview.insertSubview(labelToMove, aboveSubview: labelToStay)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a large stick for what you're probably dealing with, but this should bring something to the front:

```
parentView.bringSubviewToFront(view: targetView)
```

Answer (score 0):

PEEJWEEJ answer would be my method. Just in case I misunderstood the question you can make one invisible by changing the alpha to 0.